# C++ RegEx grouping NotePad++ Source Code

Tags: c++, regex, visual-c++, match, grouping

This line from notepad++ source code to match URL, **REGEX**

```
[A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\+~.:?&@=/%#,;\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]\\|\\*\\!\\\\]+
```

I want to match URL or Function, how to group this code with Function RegEx code. I tried

```
([A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\+~.:?&@=/%#,;\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]\\|\\*\\!\\\\]+)|(.*?\(.*?\))
```

`(.*?\(.*?\)` is my Function RegEx, don't know weather its correct. I group Function RegEx and URL RegEx using `()|()`

I failed, **What should be exact code to group both RegEx of Function and URL in C++**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found answer,

```
([A-Za-z]+://[A-Za-z0-9_\\-\\+~.:?&@=/%#,;\\{\\}\\(\\)\\[\\]\\|\\*\\!\\\\]+)|([a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\([a-zA-Z0-9_]*\\))
```

`|` to join two regex
`()` to make a group of regex
`\\` is escape chracter
`*` to match zero or greater
`+` to match at least one and greater
`[]` to make group of character